# Trying to use get_sites() and make a shortcode in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, multisite

I'm trying to make a shortcode that creates a list of all my sites in my multi-site wordpress network. The idea is I use [list_sites] in the body of the page and I get a list of all my sites.

I'm using get_sites because I'm on version 4.8.3.

When I add this function to my parent theme's functions.php file, I get a 500 internal error.

I tried using a plugin called Code Snippets to add this code, but I get this error which gives a clue:

The snippet has been deactivated due to an error on line 11:
syntax error, unexpected '['

Every example code I've seen online seems to use the same syntax so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
function make_list_shortcode() {

$subsites = get_sites();

if ( ! empty ( $subsites ) ) {

    echo '<ul class="subsites">';

    foreach( $subsites as $subsite ) {

        $subsite_id = get_object_vars( $subsite )["blog_id"];
        $subsite_name = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->blogname;
        $subsite_link = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->siteurl;
        echo '<li class="site-' . $subsite_id . '"><a href="' . $subsite_link . '">' . $subsite_name . '</a></li>';

    }

    echo '</ul>';

}

}
add_shortcode('list_sites', 'make_list_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a couple of different things wrong. You should not echo shortcode output, you should return it. Also, you're not accessing your object properties the right way. Try the below code:

```
function make_list_shortcode() {

    $subsites = get_sites();

    if ( ! empty ( $subsites ) ) {

        $html = '<ul class="subsites">';

        foreach( $subsites as $subsite ) {

            $subsite_id = $subsite->blog_id;
            $subsite_name = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->blogname;
            $subsite_link = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->siteurl;
            $html .= '<li class="site-' . $subsite_id . '"><a href="' . $subsite_link . '">' . $subsite_name . '</a></li>';

        }

        $html .= '</ul>';
        return $html;

    }

}
add_shortcode('list_sites', 'make_list_shortcode');
```

Comment: Thanks Spartacus, it works perfectly now. How would I go about alphabetizing the list? I was thinking sort($subsite_name) but I don't think it'll work since it's a property and not an array.

Comment: Read https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sites/ ... You can pass an argument for sort order